# Dagger crash after removing ButterKnife

Tags: android, dagger-2, butterknife, kotlin-android-extensions, kapt2

I was using Dagger and butterknife together. Now I was removing butterknife as I now use kotlin synthetic properties for this. But when removing butterknife from the project I am getting this dagger crash when building:

```
:android:compileWithMapsWithAnalyticsForPlayDebugKotline: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreElements.asType(MoreElements.java:126)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreElements.getAnnotationMirror(MoreElements.java:212)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.MoreElements.isAnnotationPresent(MoreElements.java:199)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectValidator.validateMembersInjectionType(InjectValidator.java:263)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.tryRegisterMembersInjectedType(InjectBindingRegistry.java:264)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectBindingRegistry.tryRegisterMembersInjectedType(InjectBindingRegistry.java:248)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep$1.visitVariableAsField(InjectProcessingStep.java:69)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep$1.visitVariableAsField(InjectProcessingStep.java:59)
    at javax.lang.model.util.ElementKindVisitor6.visitVariable(ElementKindVisitor6.java:229)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.java.model.elements.JeVariableElement.accept(JeVariableElement.kt:51)
    at dagger.internal.codegen.InjectProcessingStep.process(InjectProcessingStep.java:58)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:329)
    at dagger.shaded.auto.common.BasicAnnotationProcessor.process(BasicAnnotationProcessor.java:182)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.AbstractAnnotationProcessingExtension.doRound(AnnotationProcessingExtension.kt:312)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.AbstractAnnotationProcessingExtension.process(AnnotationProcessingExtension.kt:252)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.AbstractAnnotationProcessingExtension.doAnnotationProcessing(AnnotationProcessingExtension.kt:239)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.annotation.AbstractAnnotationProcessingExtension.analysisCompleted(AnnotationProcessingExtension.kt:131)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:160)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.resolve.jvm.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegrationWithCustomContext(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:362)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:126)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:355)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:130)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:183)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:52)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.exec(CLICompiler.java:199)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.compileNotIncremental(Tasks.kt:594)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:419)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile.callCompiler(Tasks.kt:151)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.AbstractKotlinCompile.execute(Tasks.kt:117)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$IncrementalTaskAction.doExecute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:158)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.DefaultTaskClassInfoStore$StandardTaskAction.execute(DefaultTaskClassInfoStore.java:118)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:233)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:74)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
    at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$4.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:186)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:53)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:183)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:33)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:112)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:91)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:63)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:92)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:79)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:59)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:293)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

these are the only changes between a working build and a failing build:

```
diff --git a/android/build.gradle b/android/build.gradle
index af96b92..23d976f 100644
--- a/android/build.gradle
+++ b/android/build.gradle
@@ -118,7 +118,6 @@ android {

 dependencies {
     kapt "com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:$dagger_version"
-    kapt "com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:$butterknife_version"

     provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

@@ -156,7 +155,6 @@ dependencies {


     compile 'net.lingala.zip4j:zip4j:1.3.2'
-    compile "com.jakewharton:butterknife:$butterknife_version"
     compile 'com.jakewharton.threetenabp:threetenabp:1.0.4'
     compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.0.0'

~
```

Update - interestingly it is not the removed kapt statement but the removed compile for butterknife that is causing the problem - I also get the crash leaving the kapt and removing the compile statement

Comment: It seems likely that removing Butterknife left something that gets passed to Dagger uninitialized.

However, it is hard to tell without the code.